# While loop outputs list index out of range

Tags: python

I am asked to write a code (on Python 3.6 in Spyder) that sums the indexes of the list "weights" from left to right and determine the value of k which is the max number of weights that can be added. The sum of the weights must not exceed the `THRESHOLD` value.

This is what I came up with so far.

```
THRESHOLD = 30
weights = [4, 7, 3, 5, 6, 2, 3]
accumulative_weights = 0
k = 0

while accumulative_weights <= THRESHOLD:
    accumulative_weights = weights[k] + weights[k+1]
    k += 1
```

However it outputs`IndexError: list index out of range`. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: k<=30, but weights only seven elements, so weights[k] threw the exception.

Comment: It goes out of range because you add one to k each time and k + 1 becomes larger than the size of the array before the while loop terminates.  Try adding a line: print "%s %s" % (k, len(weights)) to see whats happening

Comment: Are you sure you got the right answer? What is the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't testing for the situation (which is what is happening in this case) that you never find a sum of weights that exceed the threshold before you run out of elements in your array. Modify your code to:

```
THRESHOLD = 30
weights = [4, 7, 3, 5, 6, 2, 3]
accumulative_weights = 0
k = 0

while k < len(weights)-1 and accumulative_weights <= THRESHOLD:
    accumulative_weights += weights[k] + weights[k+1]
    k += 1
```

Comment: In the line `accumulative_weights = weights[k] + weights[k+1]` accumulative_weights does not actually accumulate

Comment: No, it didn't in the original. I thought he was looking at adjacent pairs of weights. Modified my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably caused by a mix of tabs and spaces.
you can try

```
THRESHOLD = 30
weights = [4, 7, 3, 5, 6, 2, 3]
accumulative_weights = 0
k = 0


while accumulative_weights < THRESHOLD:
        accumulative_weights = weights[k]+weights[k+1]
        k=k+1
```

but after that u will get another error for loop because lens weights 7 and u have THRESHOLD 30